# I just can't get my Facebook redirect URI whitelisted for one app, same settings work for other app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-login

I've installed the Android app on facebook developer app page, set everything in the same manner as for the app for which there was no such error. Opening for Facebook login the exact same URL that works for the other app:

```
"https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?
                    client_id=myClientId
                    &scope=publish_actions
                    &response_type=granted_scopes &redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
                );
```

I've added https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html to the Valid Oauth URIs in my app settings of course. My app has everything set the same way for both apps, except for their package names, yet for this one I get 'URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app's Client OAuth Settings.' But it is!

So I don't understand, obviously Facebook sends me the wrong error message so it's impossible to figure out where's the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by waiting about an hour and trying again. So apparently this is not mentioned in the docs anywhere but it can take really long before a new Facebook app gets registered and until then no URI can be whitelisted. This means if you just added your app and you're getting this error message no matter what you've tried of the dozens of suggestions you find on the web, it's most likely not your fault, just wait. I wish I knew this before trying all those things.